# Edit multiple records at once in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to develop a website using `asp.net mvc 4` & `EF6` where I want to update multiple records at the same time. But only one data is updating & rest are still the same. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
var resetInfo = db.myInfoes.Where(p => p.id == ClId).FirstOrDefault();
if (resetInfo != null)
{
    resetInfo.id = 0;
    resetInfo.name = "N/A";
    resetInfo.phone = "N/A"
    db.SaveChanges();
    TempData["success"] = "Information Updated Successfully!";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
{
    TempData["fail"] = "Error! Information Update Failed!";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I update the records corresponding to the id given all at once? Need this help badly. Thanks.

Comment: You make a `FirstOrDefault`... Where are your multiple records ?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` should give you a hint...

Comment: records are in MSSQL database.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, what should I use instead of `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: addition to the answers below, it would be good practice to add database related things in try catch block... in case it fails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `FirstOrDefault`... Which will retrieve only one record.

You can check if your query returns any data (instead of checking if `FirstOrDefault` returns null).

```
var resetInfos = db.myInfoes.Where(p => p.id == ClId);

if (!resetInfos.Any()) {
   //Message could be "No data to update for this client" it's not really an Update fail
   TempData["fail"] = "Error! Information Update Failed!";

   //get out of here if you have no data
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
foreach (var resetInfo in resetInfos) {
   resetInfo.id = 0;//is it possible to have multiple resetInfo with id 0?
   resetInfo.name = "N/A";
   resetInfo.phone = "N/A"
}
TempData["success"] = "Information Updated Successfully!";
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. This made me realize I still have a long way to go to understand asp.net. Tnx btw! :)

Answer (score 4):

You will require a collection, use the following code:

```
var resetInfo = db.myInfoes.Where(p => p.id == ClId).ToList();
if (resetInfo != null)
{

   resetInfo.ForEach(a =>
      {
         a.id = 0;
         a.name = "N/A";
         a.phone = "N/A";
      });
    db.SaveChanges();
    TempData["success"] = "Information Updated Successfully!";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
{
    TempData["fail"] = "Error! Information Update Failed!";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: @Farooque update `..ToList()` to `.ToList()`... theres a typo in ur answer

Answer (score 1):

You are calling FirstOrDefault() on your Where call, this will request only the first record (or a default instance of your record class if none are returned).

You probably want to instead do something like this:

```
var records = db.myInfoes.Where(p => p.id == ClId);
if (records.Any())
{
    foreach(var resetInfo in records)
    {
        resetInfo.id = 0;
        resetInfo.name = "N/A";
        resetInfo.phone = "N/A"
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
    TempData["success"] = "Information Updated Successfully!";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
{
    TempData["fail"] = "Error! Information Update Failed!";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: records can't be null, so `if records != null` is useless. You may check if records has datas, with `if records.Any`

Comment: Updated. Isn't Any a method though, not a property?

Comment: @Xefan, tnx for the response! :)